# How to convert an image file to base64 string using Arduino UNO or using any other Microcontroller?

Tags: arduino, base64

I have to convert an image file stored in the SD card to a base64 string using the Arduino.

I have used a library called base64 for Arduino, but I didn't solve my problem. Here is the library: https://github.com/adamvr/arduino-base64

Answer (score -1):

My aim was to convert image to the Base64 string format and then send this string through ESP8266 module to the webserver. 
Until now, I didn't find any solution to this problem. I found an alternative to send images taken by a camera. That alternative is a camera module with ESP32-S. This module is "ESP32-S Cam", which takes pictures and sends them to an online webserver. 
Here is the code for ESP32 Cam for taking and sending picture to the server where we will have a PHP Scrip given under this code.

```
#include "esp_http_client.h"
#include "esp_camera.h"
#include <WiFi.h>
#include "Arduino.h"

const char* ssid = "ashiq"; // my wifi "SSID" name
const char* password = "11585858"; // my wifi Password
int capture_interval = 20000; // Microseconds between captures
const char *post_url = "http://app.softwarism.com/esp32/getPhoto.php"; // Location where images are POSTED

bool internet_connected = false;
long current_millis;
long last_capture_millis = 0;

//for indicating that the picture has been taken and then sent
#define GPIO_PIN_WAKEUP GPIO_NUM_12

// CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER
#define PWDN_GPIO_NUM     32
#define RESET_GPIO_NUM    -1
#define XCLK_GPIO_NUM      0
#define SIOD_GPIO_NUM     26
#define SIOC_GPIO_NUM     27
#define Y9_GPIO_NUM       35
#define Y8_GPIO_NUM       34
#define Y7_GPIO_NUM       39
#define Y6_GPIO_NUM       36
#define Y5_GPIO_NUM       21
#define Y4_GPIO_NUM       19
#define Y3_GPIO_NUM       18
#define Y2_GPIO_NUM        5
#define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM    25
#define HREF_GPIO_NUM     23
#define PCLK_GPIO_NUM     22

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  //Setup indication pin Mode
  pinMode(GPIO_PIN_WAKEUP,OUTPUT);

  if (init_wifi()) { // Connected to WiFi
    internet_connected = true;
    Serial.println("Internet connected");
  }

  camera_config_t config;
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG;
  //init with high specs to pre-allocate larger buffers
  if (psramFound()) {
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_UXGA;
    config.jpeg_quality = 10;
    config.fb_count = 2;
  } else {
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_SVGA;
    config.jpeg_quality = 12;
    config.fb_count = 1;
  }

  // camera init
  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
  if (err != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.printf("Camera init failed with error 0x%x", err);
    return;
  }
}

bool init_wifi()
{
  int connAttempts = 0;
  Serial.println("\r\nConnecting to: " + String(ssid));
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED ) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
    if (connAttempts > 10) return false;
    connAttempts++;
  }
  return true;
}


esp_err_t _http_event_handler(esp_http_client_event_t *evt)
{
  switch (evt->event_id) {
    case HTTP_EVENT_ERROR:
      Serial.println("HTTP_EVENT_ERROR");
      break;
    case HTTP_EVENT_ON_CONNECTED:
      Serial.println("HTTP_EVENT_ON_CONNECTED");
      break;
    case HTTP_EVENT_HEADER_SENT:
      Serial.println("HTTP_EVENT_HEADER_SENT");
      break;
    case HTTP_EVENT_ON_HEADER:
      Serial.println();
      Serial.printf("HTTP_EVENT_ON_HEADER, key=%s, value=%s", evt->header_key, evt->header_value);
      break;
    case HTTP_EVENT_ON_DATA:
      Serial.println();
      Serial.printf("HTTP_EVENT_ON_DATA, len=%d", evt->data_len);
      if (!esp_http_client_is_chunked_response(evt->client)) {
        // Write out data
        // printf("%.*s", evt->data_len, (char*)evt->data);
      }
      break;
    case HTTP_EVENT_ON_FINISH:
      Serial.println("");
      Serial.println("HTTP_EVENT_ON_FINISH");
      break;
    case HTTP_EVENT_DISCONNECTED:
      Serial.println("HTTP_EVENT_DISCONNECTED");
      break;
  }
  return ESP_OK;
}

static esp_err_t take_send_photo()
{
  Serial.println("Taking picture...");
  camera_fb_t * fb = NULL;
  esp_err_t res = ESP_OK;

  fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
  if (!fb) {
    Serial.println("Camera capture failed");
    return ESP_FAIL;
  }else{
    indication();
    }

  esp_http_client_handle_t http_client;

  esp_http_client_config_t config_client = {0};
  config_client.url = post_url;
  config_client.event_handler = _http_event_handler;
  config_client.method = HTTP_METHOD_POST;

  http_client = esp_http_client_init(&config_client);

  esp_http_client_set_post_field(http_client, (const char *)fb->buf, fb->len);

  esp_http_client_set_header(http_client, "Content-Type", "image/jpg");

  esp_err_t err = esp_http_client_perform(http_client);
  if (err == ESP_OK) {
    Serial.print("esp_http_client_get_status_code: ");
    Serial.println(esp_http_client_get_status_code(http_client));
  }

  esp_http_client_cleanup(http_client);

  esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
}



void loop()
{
  // TODO check Wifi and reconnect if needed

  current_millis = millis();
  if (current_millis - last_capture_millis > capture_interval) { // Take another picture
    last_capture_millis = millis();
    take_send_photo();
    //indicate that the picture has been taken and sent
    indication();
  }
}


void indication(){
  digitalWrite(GPIO_PIN_WAKEUP,HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(GPIO_PIN_WAKEUP,LOW);
  }
```

Here is the PHP Script waiting to get the picture sent by the camera.

```
<?php
require_once("con.php"); 

$received = file_get_contents('php://input');
$fileToWrite = "uploads/smart_tick_".time().".jpg";

if(file_put_contents($fileToWrite, $received)){
echo "Uploaded";
}
?>
```

Note: Do not forget to create a folder "uploads" in the same directory where the PHP Script is.